# Adding to a dictionary directly from input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

The following snippet does what I want to do:

```
m = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
d = {}
for i in range(26):
       d[chr(i+97)] = m[i]
```

Can this be done directly while taking input itself using a generator function or something like:

`((d[chr(i+97)] = k) for i in range(26) and k in input().split())`

**EDIT**: I just found a solution; by using zip(). Like this:

```
d = {(u,v) for (u,v) in zip(m,map(int,input().split()))}
```

This works but it doesn't look ordered properly and d[chr(97)] seems missing.

Comment: `dict`s aren't ordered... what exactly are you trying to get in your `dict` and for what reason... if you could explain that, there's probably a cleaner way of doing what you're after.

Comment: I want to map every character (say a,b,c.. ) to a number from input().split()


Edit: I understand this is not OrderedDict but storing it from a-z or z-a is most efficient anyway. Still, I can't see d[a] from my approach.

Comment: This is a bit fragile. You really ought to test that `len(m)` is 26, and if it's not tell the user they didn't input the right amount of data.

Comment: It's an online coding thing and I am new to python. Switching from C++ to Python is not easy tbh. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d ={chr(i+97):x for i, x in enumerate(input().split())}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. Can you tell me what is wrong in my approach? Why doesn't it work properly?

Comment: Yep you can iter through the dictionary using `for i,m in d.iteritems():`

Comment: Which approach you mean?

Comment: d = {(u,v) for (u,v) in zip(m,map(int,input().split()))} Your approach creates a proper dictionary but it sees that mine makes a set.

Comment: Because  (u,v) mean you are creating a tuple and it makes a set out of it, since collection of tuple is a set

Comment: Ah Thanks man! and why does it start from 'b' on wards instead of 'a'? 
Last question. xD The code you write maps every character to a number. But number is also a character. so the pair is like 'a':'1'. Can't it be 'a':1?

Comment: Did mean dictionary items, if so dictionaries are not ordered. This is due to the hashing problem of how it is stored in the memory.

Comment: Last question. xD The code you write maps every character to a number. But number is also a character. so the pair is like 'a':'1'. Can't it be 'a':1?

Thanks a lot! :))

Comment: Yep, it can be done explicitly, the split() works only with strings, so your output will be string , but you can explicitly cast it to int `{chr(i+97): int(x) for i, x in enumerate(input().split())}`. Please accept the answer too. Thanks